# How to set native library path on cloudera spark yarn cluster mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I want to use jep library in my spark job. The spark is running in `yarn-cluster` mode. I am using cdh58.

I am getting this at run time:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jep in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at jep.Jep.<clinit>(Jep.java:217)
```

I tried passing it through `spark.driver.java-opts` and `spark.executor.java-opts` but its of no help. Even tried setting it in `spark-env.sh` and `hadoop-env.sh` files, it didnt work. I tried setting it in `mapreduce.map.env` and `mapreduce.map.child.env` and restarted CDH services, didnt work.

Any pointers would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environmental variable?

Comment: i tried setting it in spark.driver.extraJavaoptions and spark.executor.extraJavaOptions. I tried setting spark.appMaster.env .. Nothing works..

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @J.Done didnt arrive at any clean solution yet. Only way i got it to work was installing the library at the default python installation across all workers. Still working on it.